# Raspicam free resources

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi2

I'm trying to do basic image capture with the raspicam C++ libraries from http://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/40

The image capture generally works but seems that I can't run the program again once it's ended, or it hangs on grab_retrieve. The system requires a reboot. My guess is that something is not freeing up resources but am not sure how to diagnose that.
How can I get this utility to clean up after itself?

Code is below. Alternative suggestions are also welcome, as I am not tied to this library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "../raspicam-0.1.3/src/raspicam.h"
#include "../raspicam-0.1.3/src/raspicam_still.h"
#include "../raspicam-0.1.3/src/raspicamtypes.h"
using namespace std;

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  raspicam::RaspiCam_Still still;
  still.setEncoding ( raspicam::RASPICAM_ENCODING_JPEG );
  int length=still.getImageBufferSize();
  unsigned char *data=new unsigned char[length];

  cout<<"Capturing image at size " << length <<endl;
  if(!still.grab_retrieve(data, length)) {
    cerr<<"Error in grab"<<endl;
    return -1;
  }
  still.release();
  cout<< "Got it" << endl;
  ofstream file ( "picture.jpg",ios::binary );
  file.write ( ( char* ) data,   length );
  delete[] data;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the API, but the only issue I could see is that still.release() is not called in the if(error) block.